# Enterprise Architect, database trigger generation (oracle) and a double semicolon

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way in EA to devide all statments by semicolon and at the same time have only one semicolon after a create trigger statement?

Problem:

I'm generating triggers for a oracle db with EA 8.0 by defining the primary key as a number(18,0) and setting the AutoNum in column properties to True.
[image: Column Properties]

Then selecting following checkboxes in the 'Generate DDL' Dialog
[image: Generate DDL]

What EA generates for a trigger is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_Foo_id 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON Foo 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SELECT SEQ_Foo_id.NEXTVAL 
    INTO :NEW.id 
    FROM DUAL; 
END;;
```

Inserting that trigger into PL/SQL Developer it shows a compile error with the message

> PLS-00103: Found Symbol ";"

When doing a

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS
```

When not specifing a 'SQL Terminator' the trigger is created (because the create statement ends with one semicolon instead of two) without any error but then all other create table statements do not end with a semicolon which leads to a 'ORA-00922: missing or invalid option' because the statements are not separated by semicolon.

I did not find a direct way to influence the trigger code being generated, only for languages like C,Java [see](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/software_development/thecodetemplateeditor.html)  but not for Database Code.

Comment: Note: I also posted the same question in the Sparx User Forum under http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=bugs

Comment: I think i have to modify the generated code anyway because PL/SQL triggers need to be terminated with and ending slash see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752708/oracle-script-problem-create-trigger-not-terminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the same generation with Enterprise Architect Version 9.3.934 which generates the trigger like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_Foo_id 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON Foo 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SELECT SEQ_Foo_id.NEXTVAL 
    INTO :NEW.id 
    FROM DUAL; 
END;
/
```

So it seems to be a Bug in the old version